# how to concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects

Tags: python

I have the following tuple:

```
out = [1021,1022 ....]  # a tuple
```

I need to iterate through some records replacing each the numbers in "Keys1029" with the list entry. so that instead of having:

```
....Settings="Keys1029"/>
....Settings="Keys1029"/>
```

We have:

```
....Settings="Keys1020"/>
....Settings="Keys1022"/>
```

I have the following:

```
for item in out:
    text = text.replace("Keys1029","Keys"+(str(item),1))
```

This gives TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects.

Can someone advise me on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Minor: Note that Python uses square brackets `[]` for _lists_ and parentheses for tuples. So what you actually have there is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for item in out:
    text = text.replace("Keys1029","Keys"+str(item))
```

I removed the () around str, as (..., 1) makes it a tuple.

Answer (score 4):

You have some unnecessary parentheses, try the following:

```
for item in out:
    text = text.replace("Keys1029", "Keys"+str(item), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"Keys"+(str(item),1)
```

`"Keys"` is a string and `(str(item), 1)` is a tuple. You cannot concatenate them. Try doing.

```
"Keys"+str(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `[1021,1022 ....]` is a list, not a tuple. `(1021,1022 ....)` would be a tuple.

`item` is a number, `str(item)` is a string containing this number. Use `"Keys"+str(item)` to concatenate two strings. There is no need to create a tuple.

Also you can use formatting method: `"Keys%d" % item`.

Answer (score 0):

`text.replace("Keys1029","Keys%s"%item)`

should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.sub` with a replacement function to do this. So for each matching pattern you take the next item from your `out` list, and use that as a replacement. Note that you will get an exception thrown if there aren't enough `out`s, but not the other way around.

An advantage of this approach is that it does the replacements all in one go - so you don't need to do a `str.replace` for as many items as there are in `out`.

Also, if you so wanted and it was suitable, you could ditch `out` as is and use something such as `out = itertools.count(1021)` and that'd give you an iterable of increasing  integers starting with 1021.

**example based on OP**

```
out = [1021, 1022]

text=  """
....Settings="Keys1029"/>
....Settings="Keys1029"/>"""

import re
print re.sub('(Settings="Keys)(.*?)(")', lambda m, n=iter(out): m.group(1) + str(next(n)) + m.group(3), text)
```

Then you end up with:

```
....Settings="Keys1021"/>
....Settings="Keys1022"/>
```