# Python HTML in string variable

Tags: python, fpdf

I'm making use of FPDF in python to generate an invoice in PDF through a function. I build a table in HTML using a string variable and the loop through a list which has barcodes to populate the lines of the table  tags.

The problem I'm having is that I keep getting this TypeError `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str` when I try and generate the PDF, this happens when the loop is entered and the HTML variable amended with the row HTML string.

Initial HTML variable with the table tags looks like this:

```
html = """<table border="0" align="left" width="100%"><thead><tr><th align="left" width="25%">Code</th><th align="left" width="25%">Title</th><th align="left" width="25%">Variant</th><th align="left" width="25%">Price</th></tr></thead><tbody>"""
```

Then the for loop looks like this, where it amends the `<td>` rows to the table string variable:

```
for sku in _skus:
        prod_info = finder(sku) #returns a JSON object from mongodb
        html += "<tr><td>", str(prod_info['varsku']), "</td><td>", str(prod_info['prodtitle']), "</td><td>", str(prod_info['vartitle']), "</td><td>", str(prod_info['varprice']), "</td></tr>"
html += str("</tbody></table>")
pdf.write_html(html)
```

This is what prod_info looks like at this stage after coming from `finder()`:

```
{"prodvendor": "Elpaso", "vartaxable": "false", "varquantity": "1", "varid": "33210590148", "varprice": "235.00", "prodtype": "Type1", "varcreated": "_varCreated", "prodtitle": "3 Way Cora Hols - Piol", "varsku": "102-10001-CRD-G19", "vartitle": "C P0 / Gk 19/23", "varoption": "C P0 / Gk 19/23", "_id": {"$oid": "58e77040da522f333c757852"}, "prodid": "9665780932"}
```

this is where I get the `TypeError`.

I have tried to convert everything to string to patch the "string" variable but still, I get the TypeError.

Any help will be much appreciated.

**{{ Update }}**

```
def finder(_sku):
    result = collection.find_one({"varsku":_sku})
    if result == None:
        return "None"
    else:
        return dumps(result)
```

Comment: What you mean by "JSON object"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was with the way I construct the `html` string  variable.

When using a comma `,` in the variable it means the variables are seen as tuples: The comma `,` in the separation between string and variable indicates a tuple.

```
html += "<tr><td>", str(_code), "</td><td>", (_prodtitle), "</td>"
```

This means you are combining string:

```
html += "<tr><td>"+str(_code)+"</td><td>"+str(_prodtitle)+"</td>
```

It solved the `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects` problem.

And the below solved the initial `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str` problem.

```
prod_info = json.loads(finder(sku))
```

[Thanks to this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570804/how-to-concatenate-str-and-tuple-objects)  and thanks to  @el.pescado and @Ultcyber

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this is something you have already done, but the error you're getting would likely indicate that the prod_info variable is not of type dictionary, but string.

I would suggest using json.loads.

```
import json
prod_info = json.loads(prod_info)
```

This will enable accessing the properties.

Comment: I have included the `finder()` function and the output of `prod_info` as it comes from `finder()`

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting `prod_info` to be `dict`, but int fact it's a `str`, thus the error *"TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str"*.

```
prod_info = finder(sku) #returns a JSON object from mongodb
```

There's no such thing as "JSON object" in Python. You can have either ordinary Python data structures such as `list`s and `dict`s or strings with JSON-serialized data structures. In latter case (and `TypeError` suggests that's the case), you cannot directly manipulate those data structures. JSON string has to be decoded to native data structures first.

You should use something like:

```
prod_info = json.loads(finder(sku))
```

or, better, modify `finder` function so it handles decoding JSON internally.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have updated my question to included the `finder()` function.

Comment: When I change the `prod_info` variable to reflect your suggestion then I get another TypeError saying that str and tuples can not be concat'd `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects`

Comment: I included the output of `prod_info` too in my question.